# Creating Instances of Objects with a Constructor Function [ Unexpected Token Error ]

Tags: javascript, constructor

I will admit I am a Javascript newbie and am learning my way through Free Code Camp (coming from an HTML/CSS background, primarily).

I'm currently working on an exercise to create an instance of an object using a constructor function.

The constructor function is formatted thus:

```
var Cat = function() {
  this.whiskers= 10;
  this.legs = 4;
  this.tails= 1;
};
```

I have then assigned an instance of this constructor like this:

```
var myCat = new Cat();
```

These tests run fine.  However, once I create a new property (nickname) to myCat, I get an unexpected token error.  I have looked up and down at examples and it seems to be formatted this way, but I'm unsure what I'm missing here:

```
var myCat.nickname = "Spot";
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Remove `var` from `var myCat.nickname ...`, it's purposed to declare variables only.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, I figured it out right when you answered!